# SPServices SPDisplayRelatedInfo displayFormat:"none"

Tags: spservices

I am having an issue when using the `displayFormat: "none"` with `SPDisplayRelatedInfo`.

My plan is to populate fields on the new and edit forms with the data from the selected lookup item.

When I set displayFormat to "list" or "table" it's working. The little div is inserted in the form and presents the "related info".

I am using the `completefunc` option and want to pass the data into a function so I can populate the appropriate fields.

But no matter what the xData and Status are undefined. I read somewhere setting the displayFormat to "none" and passing the data to the completefunc would be the way to go but I'm having no luck with that.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: You should add your code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in `SPServices`. The impetus for adding `displayFormat: "none"` to `SPDisplayRelatedInfo` in `SPServices` was a blog post by Mikael Svenson titled [Using SPServices to help populate fields in a SharePoint form](https://www.techmikael.com/2016/02/using-spservices-to-help-populate.html). In the post he describes how he extended `SPServices.SPDisplayRelatedInfo` with `displayFormat: "none"`.

Later, Marc Anderson added it to SPServices. Mikael mentioned in the related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/sympmarc/SPServices/issues/28) that the `xData` structure needs to be passed to `completefunc`, but it doesn't look like that was done. From `SPServices v2014.02`, the function `showRelated` ends with:

```
// If present, call completefunc when all else is done
if (opt.completefunc !== null) {
    opt.completefunc();
}
```

i.e. no arguments are passed to your `completefunc`.

It wouldn't be that hard to fix. The call back to your `completefunc` needs to be moved up a couple of lines so it's inside the internal `completefunc` (right now it's at the end of showRelated, which means that it gets called before the async operation is actually completed), and then pass `xData` to it.

BTW, this is fixed in SPServices 2.0, but that's currently in pre alpha status. Still, you could look at the [source code for SPDisplayRelatedInfo](https://github.com/sympmarc/SPServices/blob/master/src/value-added/SPDisplayRelatedInfo.js) if you don't understand my description of the fix. He's basically done exactly what I describe above.